# jquery effect move imagen

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi every one I want to try this effect

I click in a imagen (image of pfd) and when I do this the user see like a imagen (or something) move very fast to a item menu, and show to the user that something is save (a pfd is save)

when I clink in this item of menu I will see all the pdf save.

exist a plugin n jquery or something similar.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer, I put the code here for someone.
This is my link

```
 <img id="libro" class="pull-right" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['libro'][]=1 ?>" src="<?php echo JURI::root()?>/images/about/booklet.png"/>



var animatepos;
    $("#libro").click(function(){
        var current= $("#libro").clone();
        current.attr('id', 'newLibro');
        current.toggleClass('pull-right librovolatil');
        current.insertBefore("#libro");
        //$('body').append(current);
        current.offset($('#libro').offset());
        var posInicial= current.offset();
        var posDestino= $(".item-122").offset();

        var arriba= posDestino.top - posInicial.top;
        var der= posDestino.left - posInicial.left;
        animatepos = {"marginTop": arriba,
            "marginLeft": der
        };
        current.animate(animatepos
            , "slow", "", function(){
                current.remove();
            });
```